# Find the nearest neighbour for points in one layer to points in another, then measure the distance

Tags: pyqgis, nearest-neighbor, distance-matrix

USING **QGIS 2.18.19** with python console (planning to upgrade to the newest QGIS after this piece of programming)

I am struggling with finding the correct pyQGIS coding for this.

I have a shapefile containing points marking shelteredHousing and another shapefile containing groceryStores (points).

I wish to identify the nearest grocery store to each fox den point and calculate the distance between them.

This is as far as I have managed so far (and it's taken a long time)

```
import qgis.utils
layers = iface.mapCanvas().layers()
storesData=0
housingData=0
for layer in layers:
    layerName = layer.name()
    if layerName == "grocerystores":
        groceryStoresLayer = layer
    storesData=1
    if layerName == "shelteredhousing":
        shelteredHousingLayer = layer
    housingData=1
if storesData==0:
    DestinationLayer=iface.addVectorLayer("C:\\destinationpathway\\grocerystores.shp", "groceryStoresLayer", "ogr")
if housingData==0:
    DestinationLayer=iface.addVectorLayer("C:\\destinationpathway"\\shelteredhousing.shp, "shelteredHousingLayer", "ogr")
res = shelteredHousingLayer.dataProvider()
```

I think I need to have in the statement "from math import sqrt" and then perform a square route on the different layers, but I really wanted to see if someone could give a little help or nudge in the right direction.

Effectively I'm pretty sure I want to do the distance matrix on the data, but I don't know how to plug that in.

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @peterWeb! I think there's an available tool for this: **Distance to nearest hub**. If you want to see the code, see its [script on GitHub](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/qgis/HubDistanceLines.py)